# Best practices for Magento 2 Pipeline Deployment, upgrading, using git

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, git

I'm currently running a Magento 2.3.4 Community Edition site on a set of dedicated servers. We use several third-party extensions and have also developed our theme and a few extensions for our internal use. Right now our development, build, and deployment process is fairly manual with no source control. I would like to move to the Pipeline Deployment model as described in this document: [Pipeline Deployment](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/deployment/) and start using git for source control. However, I have a few questions about this model that I haven't been able to answer from looking at the document or other internet sources:

1. In the Pipeline Deployment document, under Development System Setup requirements, it says "All Magento code is under source control in the same repository as the build and production systems". What does "all Magento code" refer to? Does this mean all of the core Magento code as provided by Magento's distribution, or does this just mean any Magento-related code you have written yourself?
2. There are notes that on the development system you should exclude the vendor directory from source control, but for the build system it doesn't mention excluding it. So does that mean on the build system you would check all of the vendor code into source control?
3. In general it's not clear to me what code is pulled from your git repo and what code is pulled from elsewhere. I'd love to see an example of someone's pipeline deployment repo to see how this is set up.
4. If you're using Pipeline Deployment, and you want to upgrade to a new version of Magento, how do you do that? This isn't covered either in Magento's upgrade documentation or Pipeline Deployment documentation. Do you do the upgrade on your build system and commit the upgraded files to the repo, and then do a pull in production to upgrade? Or do you run the upgrade on each server individually?
5. How do you handle upgrades with Pipeline Deployment when you have multiple production servers?

I appreciate any insight folks can provide, or links to any documentation I may not have seen that help explain any of these scenarios.

Comment: Hi I can't answer all your points but I can at least help with point 2. Typically you don't need to version your vendor files at all as these are your core Magento files. If they ever get overwritten by accident you can simply remove the directory and run 'composer install' to regenerate them. So, you can almost use composer as the version controlling for the core. if you ever feel like you're going to need multiple magento versions of the build server then you can version them, but they should never change unless a core upgrade/downgrade happens.

Comment: @A.Fletcher -- Thanks for your reply. One thing I don't quite get, in Step 7 here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/deployment/pipeline/build-system.html#set-up-the-build-system, it says to comment out certain lines in the .gitignore file and then commit it to the repo for "build and production." Wouldn't this mess things up the next time you pulled to development - you'd have to uncomment them there, and repeat each time you moved from dev to build/prod. Am I understanding this correctly?